# Room Database Returns Null Using Coroutine Async

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently trying to get data out of my Room Database without using a ViewModel. This is because I am working on a NotificationHandler which can be triggered at any point by an Alarm Manager.

Below is my code so far. This code below starts with a call to `sortNotification` from another class. `sortNotification` then calls `launchAsyncTask` which inturn goes off to the database by calling `getQuotesFromDatabase`. I then wait for the results (I believe), assign the data from the database to `listOfQuotes` variable, then call `displayNotification` to use it. My issue is, `listOfQuotes` is always null when I am trying to use it `displayNotification`.

Now I know the database has content as when I open my application and go to an Activity which has a ViewModel, the data is retrieved successfully. I think my issue is likely to be with the async task not completing properly or with my coroutineScope. I just need `listOfQuotes` to have data when the code gets into `displayNotification`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
private var job = Job()
private val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
private lateinit var listOfQuotes: LiveData<List<DefaultQuote>>

fun sortNotification() {
    launchAsyncTask()
}

private fun launchAsyncTask() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    val asyncTask = ioScope.async {
        getQuotesFromDatabase()
    }
    listOfQuotes = asyncTask.await()
    displayNotification()
}

private suspend fun getQuotesFromDatabase(): LiveData<List<DefaultQuote>> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val defaultQuoteDao = QuoteDatabase.getDatabase(context, this).defaultQuoteDao()
        val defaultQuoteRepository = DefaultQuoteRepository(defaultQuoteDao)
        defaultQuoteRepository.allQuotes
    }
}

private fun displayNotification() {
    val quote = listOfQuotes.value?.let {
        val size = it.size
        val randomIndex = (0..size).random()
        it[randomIndex]
    } ?: throw NullPointerException("Quotes not found")

// ... then do notification stuff
```

I have also added in the code from my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface DefaultQuoteDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $DEFAULT_TABLE_NAME")
    fun getAllQuotes(): LiveData<List<DefaultQuote>>
}
```

And the code from my repository:

```
class DefaultQuoteRepository(private val defaultQuoteDao: DefaultQuoteDao) {
    val allQuotes: LiveData<List<DefaultQuote>> = defaultQuoteDao.getAllQuotes()
}
```

And the code for `QuoteDatabase.getDatabase(Context, CoroutineScope)`:

```
fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): QuoteDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    QuoteDatabase::class.java,
                    DATABASE_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(QuoteDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem is you are never observing the value of the `listOfQuotes` LiveData. This is required to initiate the fetch from the database.

Overall you're doing this in a strange way. You should use *either* coroutines or LiveData. Both of them allow you to observe data in the database, but you don't need both. That would be like wrapping an async call inside and async call then having to unwrap them both. You should either:

1. Remove coroutines and synchronously return the LiveData and observe it.
2. Use Flow to return `Flow<List<DefaultQuote>>` from your dao function `getAllQuotes`

I recommend 2. if you expect your application to become medium large or complex. `Flow` allows you to map or combine data in a more succinct and flexible manner.

Then, your function `sortNotification` would become:

```
// Ideally this should be injected into the class, but for a Service that's a little difficult. 
// At a minimum you should initialize it once for the class
val defaultQuoteRepository: DefaultQuoteRepository by lazy { 
    DefaultQuoteRepository(QuoteDatabase.getDatabase(context, this).defaultQuoteDao())
}

fun sortNotification() {
    defaultQuoteRepository.allQuotes
        .map { listOfQuotes ->
            listOfQuotes.random()
        }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .onEach { randomQuote ->
            displayNotification(randomQuote)
        }
        // This makes the above onEach lambda run on the main thread so you're safe to show notifications. 
        // Ideally you should have a specific scope defined but tbh if you're not testing it's not that important
        .launchIn(GlobalScope)

}
```

Comment: In this case I would do this in the init { }, and instead of calling .onEach() and .launchIn() I would call .asLiveData() and assign it to the randomQuoteLiveData.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This has cleared a big part of my question up.  I am not currently using a ViewModel in this area of my application. Therefore, I need to likely add one in. My issue is that this class gets called from a Broadcast Reciever and is not associated with any views (fragments/activities). 

The class above where I have the `sortNotification` function looks like `class NotificationHandler(private val context: Context) `, hence no ViewModel. 

I now need to work how to implement your suggestion with a ViewModel.

Comment: in that case don't use `LiveData` at all! There's no point as it's sole purpose is to react to view lifecycle. Just run your `displayNotification` function and you're good!

Comment: Thanks Carson. I really don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place. I have added a new (but similar) function to my DAO and repository, just not using LiveData. It now works perfectly.